# Add single jar (dependency) to a shared Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, jar

I have a small project with 4 or 5 programmers. 
All using mac, windows or linux. All using eclipse. We are using github. Git ignoring .metadata and including the entire workspace.

In the entire project there is going to be only one external jar to be added. Other questions, similar to this one, said to use maven or similar. But for a single file there must be a better way. 
The jar is in myWorkspace/project/myJar.jar

How can i added and have it working for everyone when they pull from github?

Comment: maven is not ONLY about dependency management, it is also a build system, and i strongly recommend looking into it.

Comment: You could add it to your build path with a single right click, Build Path > Add To Build Path.

Comment: if you absolutely have to, you can just push the jar to your repo. this isn't really something i would recommend, but surely possible

Comment: You can use Intellij to add a whole directory and tell all of you to add all dependency to a fixed directory .

Comment: if the problem is how to add it to the build path - well, eclipse has had an abstraction between the actual JDK and the project for a while now, so you could just commit your .project and .classpath files, and just ensure the JDKs configured in the eclipses are mapped correctly to the execution environments. but, again, i would strongly recommend maven. it's worth it, even for a small team.

Comment: Git might ignore .metadata but not the .classpath file created by eclipse. So, check in the same in your Git and ask the fellow team members not to overwrite the same.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to answer this.
So, the solution was to have everybody pull the project. Add the jars to their builpath and add .gitignore the .classpath and .project files.
Thanks to Shinchan and everyone else that answered.